# My keyboard freezes once session starts on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb, updates, keyboard, input-devices

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. (gnome clasic).
I was working as usual and my keyboard stops working after about 1 hour.
I restart the computer. Logged as ausual; keyboard works to write my user password, session starts (seems normal), try to use the keyboard ...
It does not respond, other things look normal.

I reset the computer (advanced mode) root session and try some restore utilities as dpkg and apt, etc. Then restart without success

I read and try some (acepted) posted solutions like:
[sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015366/keyboard-and-mouse-not-working-after-sudo-upgrade-inside-vm) without success.

I found there were a similar bug reported for ubuntu 16.10 [after starting ubuntu 16.10 -- no keyboard, no mouse](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1630245?comments=all)

I found there are a reported linux kernel bug asociated with usb ports:
I'll post two links as plain text because they are externals:
    http://hamwaves.com/usb.autosuspend/en/ Fixing Usb Autosuspend Note it did not work for me.
**and the main info on usb topic:** https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt **USB power management**

What to do?

Comment: What make and model of keyboard do you have? Does your keyboard work normally in Windows or another OS?

Comment: Yes they do. I have a dual boot system. They work using Windows7

Comment: What make and model of keyboard do you have? Can you include the output of `xinput` in your question?

Comment: I logged as root (advanced mode in grub): wrote sudo -i; pass; lsusb -s 2 and got Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045e:0750 Microsoft Corp. Wired KeyBoard 600